# passing parameters into stored procedures classic asp

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, vbscript, asp-classic

I've asked a similar question before and although I've attempted to fix my previous code i now end up with an error "Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another". I want to pass a single character as a parameter to query a database then use recordset to print out to a webpage. My classic asp code is below

```
Set objCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
set objComm = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

objCon.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=xxxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxxx;Initial Catalog=Movies;Data Source=xxxx-PC"
objCon.open objCon.ConnectionString

objComm.ActiveConnection = objCon.ConnectionString
objComm.CommandText = "Paging_Movies"
objComm.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

Set objParameter = objComm.CreateParameter
objParameter.Name = "alphaChar"
objParameter.Type = adChar
objParameter.Direction = adParamInput
objParameter.Value = "a"

objComm.Parameters.Append objParameter

set objRs = objComm.Execute
```

Also my stored procedure is below -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Paging_Movies
@alphaChar char(1)
AS
if @alphaChar = '#'
    select * from Movies where movies like '[^a-z]%'
else
    select * from Movies where movies like @alphaChar + '%'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you're adding the parameter twice.  Try to replace:

```
objComm.ActiveConnection = objCon.ConnectionString
objComm.CommandText = "Paging_Movies"
objComm.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

Set objParameter = objComm.CreateParameter
objParameter.Name = "alphaChar"
objParameter.Type = adChar
objParameter.Direction = adParamInput
objParameter.Value = "a"

Set objParameter = objCommand.CreateParameter ("alphaChar", adChar, _
    adParamInput, "a")

objComm.Parameters.Append objParameter
```

with just:

```
objCommand.CreateParameter ("alphaChar", 129, 1, 1, "a")
```

Edited as your comment suggests to use the numeric values for `adChar` (129) and `adParamInput` (1) from the [W3Schools CreateParameter page](http://www.w3schools.com/ado/met_comm_createparameter.asp).

Comment: unfortunately I end up with a type mismatch?

Comment: @kurupt89: Try to specify a length of 1?  [See this manual page.](http://www.w3schools.com/ado/met_comm_createparameter.asp)

Comment: thanks ur response helped me find the answer. I had to change adChar and adParamInput to there numeral representations aswell